# Media key support in Songbird?

Tags: media-keys, songbird

I've been trying to get media keys on my keyboard to work in Songbird. (next, previous, pause and stop). but nothing seems to help

I also cant find any windows plug ins that do that either

I'm running windows 7 64bit pro with a Microsoft Wireless keyboard 2000 v2.

The media keys work for other audio applications such as Spotify so I don't know whats going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this program would help you out?:

http://www.ghacks.net/2009/01/23/media-keyboard-support-for-unsupported-media-players/

Alternatively, There is Hotkeys option in Songbird to use global hotkeys on Windows.
Go to Tools -> Options -> Hotkeys. Try to assign your Multimedia Keys in there. Some keyboard are equipped with single multimedia keys. You might have a problem with single keys. Global hotkeys are used with modifiers (Ctrl, Win, Shift, Alt). use modifiers with any single keys (letters, digits, arrows).

(The above found on: http://getsatisfaction.com/songbird/topics/my_multimedia_keys_on_songbird_0_6_1_windows_vista_don_t_work)

Comment: Ended up having to custom map my media keys to a macro that was then caught by the hotkeys in songbird. Not ideal but works. Its unusual that these specific keys aren't properly supported in Songbird but are in other media programs!